# Separate a row of data on different columns with the count of each item

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with two columns where I want to separate the second one (delimited by |) into many columns where each column has the name of the item and the observation has the count.

```
id     column
1       a|b|a
2       a|b|c|d|e
3       a|c|c
```

I would like to have columns with the name of each item and its count. for example for user 1 it would be as follows:

```
id    a    b     c     d     e
1     2    1     0     0     0
2     1    1     1     1     1
3     2    0     1     0     0
```

How do I get to separate this data such that the values are distributed in columns as such?

Comment: Given your input data, I think `id = 3` should have `a = 1` and `c = 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tidyverse approach, assuming data frame named `mydata`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>% 
  separate_rows(column, sep = "\\|") %>% 
  count(id, column) %>% 
  spread(column, n) %>% 
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)  # or just spread(column, n, fill = 0)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     id     a     b     c     d     e
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1     0     0     0
2     2     1     1     1     1     1
3     3     1     0     2     0     0
```